# Disable tab key focusing while Bootstrap modal is active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap 3, I have a modal window that pops up when you click a `.btn` link.

When it is active, users can still press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus on links and buttons in the background, some of which have tooltips and such. When these links are focused on, their tooltips overlap the modal window, which looks kind of silly.

Is there a way to disable <kbd>Tab</kbd> while the modal window is active, and re-enable <kbd>Tab</kbd> when it closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the tab key with the following.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You will want some kind of check in there to also see if the modal window is open before calling `e.preventDefault()` You can do this by setting a flag on modal open/close or simply checking if the dom element is visible.

Answer (score 8):

This solution still allows the tab key to function as normal on any focusable elements within your modal. Just call it when your DOM has loaded and it'll work for any modal on your page.

```
disableTabModalShown = function () {

$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {

    var modal = $(this);
    var focusableChildren = modal.find('a[href], a[data-dismiss], area[href], input, select, textarea, button, iframe, object, embed, *[tabindex], *[contenteditable]');
    var numElements = focusableChildren.length;
    var currentIndex = 0;

    $(document.activeElement).blur();

    var focus = function() {
        var focusableElement = focusableChildren[currentIndex];
        if (focusableElement)
            focusableElement.focus();
    };

    var focusPrevious = function () {
        currentIndex--;
        if (currentIndex < 0)
            currentIndex = numElements - 1;

        focus();

        return false;
    };

    var focusNext = function () {
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex >= numElements)
            currentIndex = 0;

        focus();

        return false;
    };

    $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 9 && e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            focusPrevious();
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            focusNext();
        }
    });

    $(this).focus();
});

$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $(document).unbind('keydown');
});};
```