# How to restrict Tab Key in the modal box?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I have a modal window that pops up when you click a .btn link.

When it is active, users can still press Tab to focus on links and buttons in the background, some of which have download links. When these links are focused on and user pressed enter key the download action takeplace.

Is there a way to disable background Tab while the modal window is active?

I am using below versions:

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals (V2.4),
Angular CLI 1.6

Comment: I have found a similar issue and answer, converted the "disableTabModalShown" function to directive in my application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142244/disable-tab-key-focusing-while-bootstrap-modal-is-active

Answer (score 4):

Since the latest **ngx-bootstrap(v2.4)** does not have the fix, I created a directive to trap tab key focus in the modal box itself.

Angular Version I used is, Angular 5

My directive is below.

> Directive

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[appSdbModalFocus]'
})
export class SdbModalFocusDirective {
    KEYCODE_TAB: number = 9;

    constructor(
        private hostElement: ElementRef
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"])
    onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent): any {
        if (e.key === 'Tab' || e.keyCode === this.KEYCODE_TAB) {
            let focusableEls = this.hostElement.nativeElement;
            let modalContent = $(focusableEls).find('a, :input, [tabindex]');
            var firstFocusableEl = modalContent.first()[0];
            var lastFocusableEl = modalContent.last()[0];

            if (e.shiftKey) /* shift + tab */ {
                this.log(firstFocusableEl, lastFocusableEl, document);
                if (document.activeElement === firstFocusableEl) {
                    lastFocusableEl.focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            } else /* tab */ {
                this.log(firstFocusableEl, lastFocusableEl, document);
                if (document.activeElement === lastFocusableEl) {
                    firstFocusableEl.focus();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> HTML

```
<form appSdbModalFocus>
...
</form>
```

Created this directive with the help of [trap-focus-in-an-element](https://hiddedevries.nl/en/blog/2017-01-29-using-javascript-to-trap-focus-in-an-element)

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented this solution myself. You should accept your own answer.

Comment: It works, until I add button to the modal content (find('a, button, :input, ...). Also, it only seems to work if the directive is applied to a form. I'd like to move it upward, so it covers the entire modal (a close button on top, some buttons on bottom). Any reason the directive should not work if applied to a div that wraps the form and modal-header, modal-footer?

Comment: This solution uses $(...).find() and I've seen another similar example that uses .querySelectAll().  However, how could this be replaced using Angular's @ViewChildren?

Answer (score -1):

you should use a class on the background page, which has a `pointer-events: none;` when the modal is up. Just use ngClass so it could be dynamically changed on click your .btn, and toggled on the modal closing event.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict tab inside modal box itself?

Comment: I think that the pointer-events: none; already does it; Are you asking something like: the mouse pointer can't escape from modal box?

Comment: I want to circulate tab key inside the modal box itself like in the demo https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo. In the plugin which I am using it is not working now. I am in search of the solution for that.

Comment: as i can see in that example, you could use the pointer events! So i think you're asking how to make modal close when you click outside, don't you?